# How to use python and OpenCV to mark license plates in image

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to use a python script with OpenCV to pick out license plates in a image and return the coordinates/draw a bounding box around the license plate. My script that I wrote is not able to find the license plate, it often returns a different area of the car.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def find_license(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

    cv2.imwrite('detect.png', edged) 
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts=sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:20]

    # loop over our contours
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0,255,0), 3)

    # compute the bounding box of the of the paper region and return it
    return cv2.minAreaRect(c)
```

Comment: can you show an example of success and failed images...?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to improve your code I would suggest you try thresholding the image first to return only colours that you would associate with the license plate.

(Yellow and white in the UK, depends on your country)

This will remove all parts of the image that are not that colour and your script may have a higher chance of working

[Here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#converting-colorspaces) is a link to a *very* useful set of tutorials/tools to help you achieve this (and most other computer vision problems)

Another process that may help would be to check the length of each contour per object and discard any that do not fall under a ratio that you set (i.e the top and bottom contour are longer than the side two) as most licence plates have a *standard* size (maybe not all, again I don't know what country you are making this for)

Another approach entirely would be to train your own haar cascade classifier for license plates which would probably have an even better chance of success. To do this you will need **alot** of image containing license plates and even more **not** containing them.

[Here](http://nayakamitarup.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-make-your-own-haar-trained-xml.html) is a link to a tutorial with tools to help you achieve this.

By following the tutorial you should then end up with a .XML file that will be your new trained classifier.

[Here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#face-detection) is a link to a tutorial that will help you to *use* your new classifier. I would also suggest reading up on how haar classifiers work in general as this may give you a better understanding of what images to use to train your classifier and what preprocessing techniques you could use on your images to improve the accuracy of your classifier.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Actually useful tips. Nearly every tutorial is exactly the same thing, I think they just copy pasted each other, not even removing the useless parts. And also every tutorial is non-US plates; European plates are less decorative and easier for the basic methods to work well.